# Rails alternative to Wallabag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I love [Wallabag](https://www.wallabag.org/), but PHP kills my soul. Does anyone know of another project that uses a framework like Rails?

(PHP is great for what it does, but it's just not my style.)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look to https://github.com/cantino/ruby-readability
It's more simple than wallabag, I think it's only grab article content. But it does the job.

(thank you for loving wallabag btw)